# How to make a union query using Laravel Eloquent and Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel eloquent to CRUD data.
My Problem is, I don't know how to make UNION queries using laravel Eloquent ORM.
Can you help me to solve my problem?

This is my sample query that i want to implement in laravel Eloquent or Query Builder

```
SELECT in_records.item_id, 
       in_records.date, 
       in_records.value AS 'IN', 
       ''               AS 'OUT', 
       in_records.USER 
FROM   in_records 
UNION 
SELECT out_records.item_id, 
       out_records.date, 
       ''                AS 'IN', 
       out_records.value AS 'OUT', 
       out_records.USER 
FROM   out_records 
ORDER  BY date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$first= DB::table("in_records")
    ->select(" in_records.item_id,
        in_records.date,
        in_records.value AS 'IN',
        '' AS 'OUT',
        in_records.user");

$final= DB::table("out_records")
    ->select(" out_records.item_id,
         out_records.date,
         '' AS 'IN', 
         out_records.value AS 'OUT',
         out_records.user")
    ->union($first)
    ->get();
```

or maybe you can merge the results like this:

```
$a = Table::where('column','value')->get();
$b = Album::where('column','value')->get();
$result = $a->merge($b);
```

Comment: Thank you @Danyal Sandeelo,.. i added `DB::RAW()` query builder at the parameter of `->select()` so that i can add space column,. 
ex. 

`->select(
DB::raw(" item_id,
       date,
      items.description as 'item',
      users.name as 'user',
       '' as 'ADD',
        in_records.value as 'IN',
       '' as 'OUT',
       '' as 'BONES',
       '' as 'SCRAPS'
 "))`